# find text and replace text excel word vba

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have the following  codes

```
  Sub DocSearch()
Dim wdApp As Object, wdDoc As Object
Set wdApp = CreateObject("word.application")
wdApp.Visible = True
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\Owner\My Documents\downloads\work\M-F-380.1.doc")
With wdDoc.Content.Find
  .Text = "Date:"
  .Replacement.Text = "Datetest"
  .Wrap = wdFindContinue
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
Set wdApp = Nothing: Set wdDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

The above works fine and i  have added  the following in the  above vba codes and its not working

```
With wdDoc.Content.Find
  .Text = "Date:"
  .Replacement.Text = "Datetest"
   Text = "Prime Lending Rate"
  .Replacement.Text =" Repo Rate"
  .Wrap = wdFindContinue
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

Your  help will be highly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: **1.** You will have to use a loop if you want to replace multiple text **2.** You are missing a `.` (DOT) before the 2nd `Text`. Change `Text = "Prime Lending Rate"` to `.Text = "Prime Lending Rate"`

Comment: No, the OP doesn't need a loop,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have:

```
.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

between each set of F/R expressions, thus:

```
Sub DocSearch()
Dim wdApp As Object, wdDoc As Object
Set wdApp = CreateObject("word.application")
wdApp.Visible = True
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\Owner\My Documents\downloads\work\M-F-380.1.doc")
With wdDoc.Content.Find
  .Wrap = wdFindContinue
  .Text = "Date:"
  .Replacement.Text = "Datetest"
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  .Text = "Prime Lending Rate"
  .Replacement.Text = " Repo Rate"
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
Set wdApp = Nothing: Set wdDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```